# Loop sobre varios objetos con nombres parcialmente común

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una cantidad finita de objetos llamados **objeto_1, objeto_2,..., objeto_n**
Quisiera por ejemplo imprimir esos objetos sin tener que repetir

```
print(objeto_1)
print(objeto_2)
.
.
.
print(objeto_n)
```

Creo que se puede hacer a través de un loop pero no puedo lograrlo.
Lo que tengo hasta el momento es:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(objeto_i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo, pero no de la forma en que lo planteas. Ten en cuenta que en `print(objeto_i)` la variable `objeto_i` no es `objeto_1 .. objeto_10` según la iteración, es simplemente la variable `objeto_i` en cada vuelta. En R si necesistas acceder a una variable por nombre puedes usar la función `get()`, previamente deberías construir el nombre de ésta, en forma dinámica:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  print(get(paste0("objeto_", i)))
}
```

O bien: